# How remove disgusting disqus ads

Tags: javascript, ads, disqus

recently adult video advertisements have started appearing above Disqus comments, and I can't seem to block them no matter what. The old solutions aren't working anymore; they seem to have changed their ad-serving systems, and the codes I've written aren't effective at all.

```
"(function($){
    setInterval(() => {
        $.each($('iframe'), (arr,x) => {
            let src = $(x).attr('src');
            if (src && src.match(/(ads-iframe)|(disqusads)/gi)) {
                $(x).remove();
            }
        });
    }, 300);
})(jQuery);"
```

these codes working. not anymore.

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $("iframe[id^='dsq-app']").each(function (i, el) {
        if(i===0 || i===2) {
            el.remove();
        };
    });
});
```

these codes partly works but remove comment section aswell.

Comment: Use AdBlocker? What have you done to debug your issue?

Comment: [Change your ads settings](https://help.disqus.com/en/articles/1717058-updating-your-advertising-settings)

Comment: @CherryDT well they wants 105$ per month lmao. i'd rather remove disqus.

Comment: @CherryDT i have more than 1 million views. so its not 12$ for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.